# Is there a reason the xgboost code snippet from the usemodels package has one_hot set to TRUE?

Tags: tidymodels

Is there a reason the `recipe` code snippet for xgboost classifier has `one_hot = TRUE`? This creates "n" dummy variables instead of "n-1". I usually set it to FALSE but just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Code -

```
data <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%  
  mutate(cyl = cyl %>% as.factor)

usemodels::use_xgboost(mpg ~ cyl, data = data)
```

Output -

```
xgboost_recipe <- 
  recipe(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = data) %>% 
  step_novel(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes(), one_hot = TRUE) %>% 
  step_zv(all_predictors()) 

xgboost_spec <- 
  boost_tree(trees = tune(), min_n = tune(), tree_depth = tune(), learn_rate = tune(), 
    loss_reduction = tune(), sample_size = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost") 

xgboost_workflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(xgboost_recipe) %>% 
  add_model(xgboost_spec) 

set.seed(28278)
xgboost_tune <-
  tune_grid(xgboost_workflow, resamples = stop("add your rsample object"), grid = stop("add number of candidate points"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea there is that, as a tree-based model, xgboost can handle all the levels (unlike a linear model) and can actually require more splits to fit well if you don't include all the categories. Read [more about this here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438875/one-hot-encoding-of-a-binary-feature-when-using-xgboost).

You *don't* see the same for the ranger random forest because it can handle factors natively.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
cars <- as_tibble(mtcars) %>%  
  mutate(cyl = cyl %>% as.factor)

usemodels::use_ranger(mpg ~ cyl, data = cars)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
#> ranger_recipe <- 
#>   recipe(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = cars) 
#> 
#> ranger_spec <- 
#>   rand_forest(mtry = tune(), min_n = tune(), trees = 1000) %>% 
#>   set_mode("regression") %>% 
#>   set_engine("ranger") 
#> 
#> ranger_workflow <- 
#>   workflow() %>% 
#>   add_recipe(ranger_recipe) %>% 
#>   add_model(ranger_spec) 
#> 
#> set.seed(54153)
#> ranger_tune <-
#>   tune_grid(ranger_workflow, resamples = stop("add your rsample object"), grid = stop("add number of candidate points"))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.